# What should happen to when user changes username in Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Am pretty new to Oauth2 and I wondering what should happen in a scenario where a user changes the username used to authorize a client.

Should all access tokens expire after change is successful requesting the client to a new access code?

or

The access tokens are to be updated with the new username by the authentication server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal cases, username of a user and the unique ID of the user are different. If an access token is associated with the unique ID (not with username), you don't have to invalidate or update access tokens even if username is changed.

Otherwise, if you associate access tokens with username (not with the unique ID), when username is changed, you should invalidate access tokens or update access tokens with the new username.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth spec doesn't specify what should happen -- one the user passes authentication and gets a token, they have an active authorization "session" as long as that token is valid.

You can invalidate tokens, and authorization sessions, as you like, though. So as a matter of policy, if you want to invalidate their tokens when there's a change to the account, then you are free to do that.

Just remember to invalidate both access tokens and refresh tokens for the user, or else they might just use their refresh token to start over with a access token.